# How to construct the image of a point under inversion using angle bisector

Tags: geometry

On math.nus.edu.sg the author has an unusual construction of the image under inversion in a circle. I am searching for a proof of the construction.
Angle bisector construction of the inverse:

> The circle centred at $O$ and the point $P$ are given, as well as a point $X$ on the circle. Let $Z$ be the intersection of the circle and the ray $\overrightarrow{OP}$. Choose a point $P'$ on $\overrightarrow{OP}$ such that $\overline{XZ}$ is the angle bisector of $\angle PXP'$. Then $P'$ is the inverse of $P$ with respect to the circle.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

$$\begin{align}
\alpha + \angle PXZ \underbrace{\quad=\quad}_{\text{exterior $\angle$}} \angle XZO \underbrace{\quad=\quad}_{\text{$\triangle OXZ$ isos.}} \angle ZXP' + \beta &\quad\to\quad\alpha=\beta \\
&\quad\to\quad \triangle POX\sim \triangle XOP' \\[6pt]
&\quad\to\quad |OP||OP'|=|OX|^2 \quad\square
\end{align}$$